# How to configure AWS Cloud Trail to only record IAM activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

How do I configure AWS Cloud Trail to only record IAM activity?

Or is it possible to extract ONLY IAM activity from a cloud trail (to be accessed by a third party)?

Comment: When you create a Trail, you can specify which events it should record. So, you could create another separate Trail to what you already have, and configure it to only record IAM activity. You could then grant access to that Trail via an IAM Role.

Comment: how? dont understand.  i don't see any options for specifying services

Comment: Ah, you're right! Services can be selected for "Data Events", but I suspect IAM events would be captured in "Manage events", which doesn't offer the ability to select services.